# IndexError:too many indices scikit model when trying to predict the probabilities and storing in array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am using scikit and trying to predict the probabilities using svm and logisticregression after using the following code:

```
preds = []
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = model.predict(X_test)
print "Training time: %0.3fs" % (time() - t0)
preds.append(array(pred[:,1]))
```

Error at following line

```
preds.append(array(pred[:,1]))
```

as IndexError:Too many indices

Answer (score 0):

`predict` returns an array of most probably labels. If you want probabilities of each class, you should call `predict_proba`. Note that SVM by default does not provide probability estimates, you will need to enable it by passing `probability=True` when constructing.